# How to get the Drush output of "drush l10n-update" from the command line with PHP in Linux?

Tags: 7, drush

I am trying to print from PHP the list of my updated translations, I know that I can obtain this info using `drush l10n-update` (I have installed the l10n-update module) from the command line but I want put this command a php script, I try to obtain the info with following codes but I can't see anything:

```
//this works and I can see my enabled modules
echo passthru('drush pm-list | grep "Enabled"', $o);
// I can't see anything with this
echo passthru('drush l10n-update', $o);

//this works and I can see my enabled modules
echo exec('drush pm-list | grep "Enabled"', $o); 
// I can't see anything with this
echo exec('drush l10n-update', $o); 

//this works and I can see my enabled modules
echo system('drush pm-list | grep "Enabled"');
// I can't see anything with this
echo system('drush l10n-update');
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

I am using Drush 5.10.0 from the repo of Ubuntu

**Edit after** [Pierre answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/164461/28275):

From the command line output of `drush l10n-update-status` :

```
 Project                               Español status                 
 auto_nodetitle 7.x-1.0                Actualizado                    
 drupal 7.28                           Actualización local disponible 
 serial 7.x-1.3                        Actualizado                    
 taxonomy_container 7.x-1.1            Actualización local disponible 
 taxonomy_manager 7.x-1.0              Actualizado
```

From the command line output of `drush l10n-update` :

```
Fetching update information for all projects / all languages.                                                                                      [status]
Found 2 projects to update.                                                                                                                        [status]
Actualizando traducción.                                                                                                                          [status]
Descargando e importando archivos.                                                                                                                 [status]
WD locale: Disallowed HTML detected. String not imported:                                                                                          [warning]
WD locale: Disallowed HTML detected. String not imported: En UNIX, Linux, y Mac OS X, el archivo /etc/syslog.conf define la configuración de      [warning]
enrutamiento. Los mensajes pueden ser marcados con los códigos LOG_LOCAL0 hasta LOG_LOCAL7. Para más información sobre utilerías de Syslog,
niveles de severidad y cómo definir un archivo syslog.conf, consulte, la página del manual, de la linea de comando de syslog.conf.
WD locale: Disallowed HTML detected. String not imported: OpenID sugiere el uso de cualquiera de las  GMP matemáticas (recomendado para           [warning]
rendimiento) o  bibliotecas matemáticas BC para permitir asociaciones de OpenID.
WD locale: 3 disallowed HTML string(s) in sites/all/translations/drupal-7.28.es.po                                                                 [warning]
Imported: drupal-7.28.es.po.                                                                                                                       [ok]
Imported: drupal-7.28.es.po.                                                                                                                       [ok]
Imported: taxonomy_container-7.x-1.1.es.po.                                                                                                        [ok]
Imported: taxonomy_container-7.x-1.1.es.po.                                                                                                        [ok]
2 projects updated: drupal, taxonomy_container.                                                                                                    [status]
Spanish translation strings added: 10, updated: 0, deleted: 0.
3 translation strings were skipped because they contain disallowed HTML. See Mensajes recientes del registro for details.                          [warning]
```

As you can see the output is different, because the command `drush l10n-update` runs the batch process and import the translations.

So, I test in my php script this code:

```
exec('drush l10n-update-status', $output) . '<br>';

echo '<pre>';
print_r($output);
echo '</pre>';
```

And I can see the same output that come from the execution of `drush l10n-update-status` from the command line.

However with this code:

```
echo exec('drush l10n-update', $output); 

echo '<pre>';
print_r($output);
echo '</pre>';
```

Nothing is printed just a empty array:

```
Array
(
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Keeping track of the various Drush version IDs is not obvious, especially when it's about "which version of Drush can be used with which version of Drupal".

But nevertheless, I think it's worth looking at "[Rework drush l10n-update commands](https://www.drupal.org/node/1057150)", especially [Comment #9](https://www.drupal.org/node/1057150#comment-4264382) in it, which says:

> ... There're two new commands. In summary they are:
>
> 1. **l10n-update-refresh**
> 2. **l10n-update-status** // prints a table
> 3. **l10n-update** // not limited to a number of imports as before but runs the batch process.
>
> Commands 2 and 3 accepts `--languages=es,fr,de`.
>
> l10n-update also accepts `--mode=keep|overwrite`.
>
> Those options are validated.

So if these commands are available in your version of Drush, I'd give it a try to use `l10n-update-status` instead of `l10n-update`. If they are not available, then maybe the patch in the comment #9 somehow helps to at least understand why it's not working yet (any maybe you can think of a way to backport it also).

Comment: Is a good option, at least I can see the projects that I can update, but I need get the output of `drush l10n-update` because this command show other info (the final state after update the translations). If you want test the commands and see the output.

Comment: I edit the question with aditional information.

Comment: Hm, seems like I somehow "forgot" about this question/answer ... I might come back to it tomorrow or so. For today I call it a day ... (close to midnight over here ...). Bonne nuit!

Comment: I had some advance with your answer, but the problem don't have a solution, and I don't know why